# onChange dosent register the first key i type for my filter function (filterFn)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

onChange dosent get triggered on first change for filter function `filterFn`, the `changeDepartmentIdFilter` function dosent change the value of departmentIdFilter on first change example

if i write

> apple

it consoles only

> appl

here is the link to my whole project:

https://github.com/naveednaseer/delete_later/blob/master/frontend/src/components/Department.js

here is the code :

```
const Department = () => {


    let [department, setDepartment] = useState([])
    let [filteredDepartment, setFilteredDepartment] = useState([])
    
    let [values, setValues] = useState({
        modalTitle: '',
        departmentName: '',
        departmentId: 0,

        departmentIdFilter: "",
        departmentNameFilter: "",
        departmentsWithoutFilter: [],
    })

    useEffect (() => {
        getDepartments()
    }, [])


    let filterFn = () =>{
        let departmentIdFilter = values.departmentIdFilter
        let departmentNameFilter = values.departmentNameFilter


        let filteredData = filteredDepartment.filter(
            function(el){
                return el.DepartmentId.toString().toLowerCase().includes(
                    departmentIdFilter.toString().trim().toLowerCase()
                ) &&
                el.DepartmentName.toString().toLowerCase().includes(
                    departmentNameFilter.toString().trim().toLowerCase()
                )

            }
        )
        setDepartment(filteredData)

    }


    let changeDepartmentIdFilter = (e) => {
        setValues({...values, 'departmentIdFilter': e.target.value})
        filterFn()
    }
    
    
    let changeDepartmentNameFilter = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.value)
        setValues({...values, 'departmentNameFilter': e.target.value})
        filterFn()
    }


    let getDepartments = async () => {
        let response = await fetch (variables.API_URL + "department")
        let data = await response.json()

        setDepartment(data)
        setFilteredDepartment(data)
    }

  
    return (
        <div>

            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary m-2 float-end" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onClick={() => addClick()}>Add Department</button>

            <table className="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <input className="form-control m-2" onChange={(e) => {changeDepartmentIdFilter(e)}} placeholder='Filter' />
                            DepartmentId
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <input className="form-control m-2" onChange={(e) => {changeDepartmentNameFilter(e)}} placeholder='Filter' />
                            DepartmentName
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Options
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {department.map((dep) => 

                        <tr key={dep.DepartmentId}>
                            <td>{dep.DepartmentId}</td>
                            <td>{dep.DepartmentName}</td>
                            <td>
                                
                                {/* >>>>>>EDIT BUTTON<<<<<< */}
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-light mr-1" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onClick={() => editClick(dep)}>
                                    
                                </button>

                                {/* >>>>>>>DELETE BUTTON<<<<<<<<<<< */}
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-light mr-1" onClick={() => deleteClick(dep.DepartmentId)}>
                                    
                                </button>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        )}
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <div className="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabIndex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                <div className="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <div className="modal-header">
                            <h5 className="modal-title">{values.modalTitle}</h5>

                            <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            </button>

                        </div>

                        <div className="modal-body">
                            <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                <span className="input-group-text">Department Name</span>
                                <input name = 'departmentName' type="text" className="form-control" value={values.departmentName} onChange={(e) => {changeDepartmentName(e)}} />
                                {/* <input type="text" className="form-control" value={departmentName} onChange={changeDepartmentName} /> */}
                            </div>

                            {values.departmentId == 0 ?
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary float-start" onClick={() => createClick()}>Create</button> :
                                null
                            }

                            {values.departmentId != 0 ?
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary float-start" onClick={() => updateClick()}>Edit</button> :
                                null
                            }

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Department
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [onChange dosent get triggered on first change for filter function (filterFn)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70450421/onchange-dosent-get-triggered-on-first-change-for-filter-function-filterfn)

Comment: Please don't spam with the same posts.
I'd recommend improving the quality of the question instead. For instance, you could create a runnable code snippet that illustrates the problem you are facing without irrelevant parts.

Comment: i am sorry i wont post this question again

Answer (score 0):

Naveed when you write apple and it console appl it just because you are setting state at onChange event so state is like asynchronous so it take some time that is why this behave like it.
you can call your filter function in setTimeout like this;

```
 let changeDepartmentIdFilter = (e) => {
        setValues({...values, 'departmentIdFilter': e.target.value})
        setTimeout(() => {
           filterFn()
        },0)
}
```

Comment: oh i see that makes sense do u have any idea how i can fix it

Comment: see my answer i edit it

Comment: sorry but its not working kamlesh

Comment: oh sorry if you can upload you code on codesandbox and provide link so it will be helpful for you because i have to understand

Comment: Thanks alot kamlesh for helping me   i am not fimilar with codesandbox but i can give you the github link of the whole code      https://github.com/naveednaseer/delete_later/blob/master/frontend/src/components/Department.js

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this while using `useEffect` hook.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
   console.log(value);
   // Call filter function here
}, [value]);

const onChangeCallback= () => {
  setValue('a');
}
```

So whenever your value changes filter function gets called.